# Are expansion gaps needed when gluing down linoleum?

Tags: linoleum

I am going to fully glue down a sheet linoleum in my bathroom. I would like to know if I have to leave expansion gaps when totally gluing down the linoleum.

Comment: I found the issue is to get the joint line to match with the pattern so it can’t be seen (easily)...

Comment: To get the seam to match the best, is to lap one sheet over the other, matching the pattern and cut through both pieces with a razor knife with a fresh blade. Keeping the knife square to the cut is essential. There is also a joint sealer to keep the joint intact better?? I would have used it myself but I wasn't aware of its existence at the time. The joints I did have not failed. There were only 2, in my own home in a high traffic area

Comment: As the answers indicate, no expansion gap is necessary. If, however, you _feel compelled_ to leave a gap, do so at the edges and hide it by covering with some baseboard trim. Bear in mind what season you're installing, in though, in the summer it will be at its most expanded so don't leave any extra space. If it's winter, it will be at its most contracted, so leave a _small_ space.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no gap. When installing rolled linoleum you do everything possible not to have a gap. If you have a seam most manufacturers have matching sealer to hide and seal the seam so debris cannot get in there and look bad. So do not leave gaps and if you will have a seam get the appropriate sealer to hide it and prevent debris from building up.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen gaps at seams of sheet vinyl or linoleum. I believe in the best applications the seams are invisible. This is accomplished by proper butting without any gap, but without compressing at the joint. I advise you consult experts or authoritative sites on installation of sheet linoleum.